# How do I retain filters in JqGrid whilst still getting remote data?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using [this demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UsageFormetterSelect2.htm) to display text and dropdown list filters in the columns of a JqGrid. The grid has a remote data source and with each sort, filter, or page view etc, it grabs the data from the remote source.

The problem I am having is that when the new data arrives, the grid is refreshed, and the filters revert to default. I've looked at a few examples by Dr Oleg but I can't get it to work with remote data and persistence. Any setting of `datatype` to `"local"` or `loadonce` to `true` breaks the remote datasource.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to get this to work?

I've tried the following, but as I said, this stops the JqGrid from making API requests:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var postfilt = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters;
    var postsord = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').sord;
    var postsort = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').sidx;
    var postpage = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').page;

    console.log(postfilt);
    console.log(postsord);
    console.log(postsort);
    console.log(postsort);*/

    if ($this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
                datatype: "local",
                postData: { filters: postfilt, sord: postsord, sidx: postsort },
                search: true
            });
            $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: postpage}]);
        }, 25);
    }
}
```

I think the issue has something to do with the `select2` dropdown menus. Here you can see it destroys the filter menu and recreates it.

```
var options = colModelOptions, p, needRecreateSearchingToolbar = false;
if (options != null) {
    for (p in options) {
        if (options.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            if (options[p].edittype === "select") {
                options[p].editoptions.dataInit = initSelect2;
            }
            if (options[p].stype === "select") {
                options[p].searchoptions.dataInit = initSelect2;
            }
            $grid.jqGrid("setColProp", p, options[p]);
            if (this.ftoolbar) { // filter toolbar exist
                needRecreateSearchingToolbar = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (needRecreateSearchingToolbar) {
        $grid.jqGrid("destroyFilterToolbar");
        $grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", filterToolbarOptions);
    }
}
```

If there was a way this could be done just once per JqGrid load rather than per every request, then that may be a step in the right direction.

Comment: What you mean under "when the new data arrives"? Who initialize new loading of the data in the grid? Where you hold the filters? Do you want just the selects and inputs of searching toolbar will hold the previous values or you want that the filter will be applied on the new loaded data?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer. I set the `datatype` to `json` and the `url` to an API. The filters by default are empty. When any page is changed, or filter is set, JqGrid makes a request to my API and updates the data. Unfortunately, when it does this, it also resets the filters to empty. This is what I'm trying to persist.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was quite simple, it just didn't present itself to me until the next morning. I simply wrapped the code that built the search bar in a boolean check, so that it only loaded once.

```
// somewhere in the class
var gridLoaded = false;

// and in the JqGrid initialization 
loadComplete: function (response) {
    if (!gridLoaded) {
        var options = colModelOptions, p, needRecreateSearchingToolbar = false;
        if (options != null) {
            for (p in options) {
                console.log(p);
                if (options.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    if (options[p].edittype === "select") {
                        options[p].editoptions.dataInit = initSelect2;
                    }
                    if (options[p].stype === "select") {
                        options[p].searchoptions.dataInit = initSelect2;
                    }
                    $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", p, options[p]);
                    if (this.ftoolbar) { // filter toolbar exist
                        needRecreateSearchingToolbar = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (needRecreateSearchingToolbar) {
                $(this).jqGrid("destroyFilterToolbar");
                $(this).jqGrid("filterToolbar", filterToolbarOptions);
            }
        }
        gridLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks again to Dr Oleg for the help.